# Qual origem da palavra "lambuja"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

Desde muito pequeno ouvi muitas vezes a palavra *"lambuja"* empregada em alguma frase qualquer, porém nunca soube exatamente o que significava e qual seria sua origem.

Com o tempo, até consegui usá-la, mas sempre considerando o contexto do que já ouvia antes. Por exemplo:

> - Vamos apostar uma corrida? Te dou 5 minutos de lambuja.
> - Vamos jogar Xadrez? Te dou dois peões de lambuja.

O que significa exatamente e qual é a origem da palavra *"lambuja"*?

Comment: O que é "pinhão" neste contexto? Cada uma das oito peças mais fracas do xadrez? Eu chamo-lhe *peão*.

Comment: @Jacinto você tem toda razão. Falha nostra ao elaborar a frase. Vou corrigir! Obrigado.

Comment: Até pensei que informalmente se usasse no teu círculo de amigos *pinhão* por *peão*. Então, no teu exemplo, tu propões começar o jogo só com 6 peões, enquanto o teu adversário começa com os 8 da norma?

Comment: @Jacinto na verdade, na minha terra natal, informalmente fala "pinhão". Talvez pela força do hábito, eu coloquei exatamente como o pessoal fala lá. Mas de fato, o correto é falar "peão" como você ressaltou.

Comment: Não estava a criticar; só queria esclarecer. Esclarece também a outra coisa: dar dois pinhões ao adversário significa que tu começas só com 6 e ele com 8?

Comment: @Jacinto Eu sei que não era crítica. Quanto aos peões, sim, começar com 8 e o adversário com 6.

Comment: O contrário.   Começar com 6 e o adversário com 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao que parece, ***lambuja*** veio, via ***lambugem***, de ***lamber***. Quem havia de dizer?! *Lambugem* começou por significar ‘guloseima’, ganhando depois o sentido figurado de ‘ganho ou vantagem que se dá a alguém, especialmente para o aliciar’, que é o sentido com que *lambuja* é usado nos exemplos da pergunta.

[*Lamber* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lamber) vem já do latim *lambere*. *Lambugem* aparece em [1716 no *Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=badVS0VVqsAC&pg=PA27&dq=%22Lamb%C3%BAgem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp5I6v06fWAhVDOxQKHeevBUkQ6AEIWjAH#v=onepage&q=%22Lamb%C3%BAgem%22&f=false), com o significado aproximado de ‘guloseima, gulodice’ (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Lambugem. Comeres de pouca substancia, com que antes se satisfaz a golodice, do que a fome.

Em [1789, o dicionário de Moraes Silva](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA5&dq=%22Lambugem%20f%20f%20Comeres%20gulofos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOyIOF1afWAhXGOxoKHaydDOQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Lambugem%20f%20f%20Comeres%20gulofos%22&f=false) já acrescenta o sentido de ‘isco (para peixe)’ e de ‘ganho para aliciar’:

> LAMBUGEM , s. f. Comeres gulosos. § A ceva [isco] a que os peixes acodem. § Sopas , que se recebem por favor. § **Lucro tenuissimo, com que se engoda alguem**.

O dicionário de [Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913](https://books.google.pt/books?id=x1c0mi78WQoC&pg=PT5055&dq=%22gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o,%20luvas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitgrmM1qfWAhWKORoKHe7TC88Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22gratifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20luvas%22&f=false) acrescenta o sentido, que restringe ao Brasil, de ‘gratificação, luvas’.

Em 1964 o *Dicionário da Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa* já tem ***lambuja***, que diz ser o mesmo que *lambujem*. Entretanto o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) diz que *lambuja* é brasileirismo e só tem alguns dos sentidos de *lambujem*. Passo a citar, desenvolvendo algumas abreviações:

> **lambujem** *s.f.* (1552 cf. João de Barros, *Décadas da Ásia*) **1** ato de comer gulodices
>   **2** guloseima, lambarice **3** resto de comida deixada nos pratos **4** *Brasil* mesmo que *LAMBUJA*
>    ʘ ETIMOLOGIA radical de *lamber* sob a forma *lamb-* + terminação *-ugem* […]
>
> **lambuja** *s.f. Brasil* **1** lucro ou vantagem em jogo, aposta ou negócio **2** aquilo que se ganha ou dá além do estipulado; quebra **3** gorjeta, propina ʘ ETIMOLOGIA provavelmente alteração de *lambujem* […]

Algo parecido a esta evolução de *lambugem*, que de ‘gulodice’ passou a significar também ‘gorjeta, ganho que se dá a alguém’, aconteceu em Moçambique a [*refresco* (Priberam 7)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/refresco), que adquiriu também o significado “recompensa, geralmente ilegal, a quem proporciona ou facilita um negócio lucrativo”.

Comment: Eu encontrei dizendo que também poderia ser um verbo. Veja a conjugação: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/lambujar Será que com um tempo se tornou um verbo. Estranho isso.

Comment: Outra coisa, se _lamber_ muito a pode se _lambuzar_ e não _lambujar_. Será que teria alguma relação?

Comment: @acklay, existe também o verbo [*lambujar*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lambujar), que significa 'comer gulodices'. [*Lambuzar*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lambuzar) significa 'sujar'. Estes verbos vem todos de *lamber*; segundo o Houaiss, *lambujar* e *lambuzar* vem de uma versão mais antiga, *lambuçar*.

Comment: @acklay, o Houaiss tem uma catrefada de palavras derivadas de *lamber*: *lambareiro, lambaraz, lambiscar, lambão, lambuça, lambaças*, e muitas mais.

Comment: Obrigado Jacinto! Deu pra esclarecer bastante!

Answer (score 5):

*Lambuja* é uma vantagem que se dá a alguém em determinada situação, ou algo que se ganha além do combinado:

- O [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lambuja) define como: *"Pequeno lucro ou vantagem dado a alguém, geralmente para engodo."*
- Já a [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/lambuja) diz: *"Vantagem concedida a adversário, em jogo, aposta ou negócio"*
- O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=lambuja) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/lambuja,%20lambujem) acrescentam: *"Aquilo que se ganha ou se dá além do combinado"*

Eu sempre entendi desta forma também. Nos seus exemplos, significa exatamente isso: uma vantagem concedida ao adversário, por qualquer motivo que seja (pode ser que eu me ache tão melhor que não me importo em dar esta vantagem, ou é uma "armadilha" pois esconde alguma má intenção, etc).
Não importa o motivo, qualquer vantagem dada deliberadamente é uma *lambuja*.

Eu também uso para situações descritas pelo Michaelis (*"aquilo que se ganha além do combinado"*). Em uma feira que eu costumava ir, ao comprar uma certa quantidade de pastéis (geralmente 10 ou mais), às vezes - dependendo do humor do pasteleiro - ganhávamos outro pastel, de graça.

Então pode-se dizer que esse pastel grátis vinha *de lambuja*, já que não era uma regra fixa (nem todos que compravam a mesma quantidade ganhavam sempre um grátis). É algo "além do que foi combinado".

Quanto à origem, a [resposta do Jacinto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4772/1798) já é bem completa e não tenho o que acrescentar.

Comment: @Centaurus De fato ficou meio estranho. Fiz uma alteração, mas fique à vontade para editar se for o caso. Não estou conseguindo pensar em uma construção melhor...

Comment: Eu diria "levávamos mais um grátis", "ganhávamos um extra".  Mas também não creio que a sua forma esteja errada,  Só um pouco redundante, talvez.